# What was the thin, black object that was moving around the engine bay of SpaceX Starship SN15?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, spacex-starship-sn15

SpaceX Starship SN15 flew and landed successfully but,

A few minutes into the flight, a long, thin seemingly black object was seen moving around the engine bay

[image]

- What was this object?
- What is it used for
- Why was it loose?

Comment: Might this be a liftoff detection sensor?